# Not able to map correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to store the values from my firebase database into my RN project.

I was able to log the objects through my terminal correctly.

I'm not updating my setState correctly, the team arrays should be filling up with teamScore.

Here's my firebase data structure:
[image: firebase data]

And below is my code:

```
class WesternIndex extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dallasTeam: [],
        denverTeam: [],
        goldenStateTeam: [],
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getRef().child('Western_Teams').on('child_added', snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            // console.log(snapshot.val()) //val logs Object
            // console.log(snapshot.key)   //key logs city name
        }
        let that = this;
        this.getRef().child('Western_Teams').once('child_added', function(snapshot){
            let scores = [];
            snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
                let score = {
                    id: data.val().key
                }
                const printThis = scores.push(score);
                console.log('prints = ', (printThis)); // prints the number 1, 15 times
                that.setState({
                    teamScore: scores
                });
            });
        })
    })

    });
}

getRef = () => {
    return firebase.database().ref();
}
```

Here's what my log looks like from the val/key
[image]

And here is the log from printThis
[image]

Comment: What is the problem ? What is your question ?

Comment: i'm not updating my setState correctly, the team arrays should be filling up with teamScore

Comment: Your array `scores` has length 1. It means `function(snapshot)` is called 15 times. Do you want it to be called once and get 15 snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have (accidentally?) imbricated two listeners for your Firebase realtime database. Also, be careful that the `on('child_added')` listener will trigger for **one child at the time** so your initial `forEach` was probably wrong.

Try replacing your `componentDidMount` with this

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getRef().child('Western_Teams').on('child_added', snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            this.setState({
                teamScore: scores.concat(data.val);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

While I did not understand exactly what you were trying to achieve, this snippet should work, and lead you towards the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  I'm trying to map the key/val from the snapshot -- I believe I have to use the map method, unless I misunderstood your answer

Comment: Where would you want to do a map ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your function is called 15 times. So, every time, your array `scores` is re-created and pushed 1 element. Try to push to state directly:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getRef().child('Western_Teams').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            // console.log(snapshot.val()) //val logs Object
            // console.log(snapshot.key)   //key logs city name
        }
        this.getRef().child('Western_Teams').once('child_added', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach( (data) => {
                let score = {
                    id: data.val().key
                };
                this.setState( (prevState) => ({
                    teamScore: [...prevState.teamScore, score]
                }));
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Also, with array functions, no need of the `that = this` trick.